# Storing a gif image in android internal memory

Tags: android, image, gif

I am quite new to android. I want to save image to internal memory and later retrieve the image from internal memory and load it to image view. I have successfully stored the image in internal memory using the following code :

```
void saveImage() {
    String fileName="img"+ cnt +".jpg";
    //File file=new File(fileName);
    try 
    {

       FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
       bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code is for saving the jpg image. If I want to save a gif image how can i do that??  Please help me. I can see the options for only jpg and png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap only works with png, jpg etc, and gif is a list of images, so you have to work with it as a binary file and use [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and `write(byte[])`

Comment: Can you share some code about how to do that?? I am very new to all this.

Comment: I give you an explanation why it's not working and now, when you know what the main issue you can check google =) http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245